# ¿Cómo escribir la posición de una matriz con printf y los parámetros de posición? En C

Tags: c, matrices, printf

Este es mi código al momento de mostrar mi matriz.

```
printf("\n");
printf("----- Matriz ------\n");
printf("\n");
printf("%12s%10s\n","Posicion","Valor");

for( int i=0; i<FILA ; i++)
{
    for( int j=0; j<COLUMNA; j++)
    {
        printf("%8d%13d\n",i, matriz[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Pero al momento de correr el programa me da este resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera poder mostrar cada posicion de esta manera (0,0) (0,1) (1,1) ...
Mi problema es que se me hace complicado la sintaxis de los parámetros de posición y no encuentro mucha información, como sería la sintaxis correcta para poder mostrar la posición como lo mencioné?

Comment: hola, por favor publica el output como codigo, no como una imagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `printf` adentro de los bucles `for` debería ser algo así:

```c
printf("   (%3d, %3d) %9d\n", i, j, matriz[i][j]);
```

La explicación del string de formato (primer argumento del printf) es:

1. Tres espacios y abro paréntesis: los imprime tal cual.
2. %3d: imprime el segundo argumento (`i`) en 3 espacios con formato numérico en base 10, quedando encolumnados bajo el "Pos" de "Posición".
3. Coma y espacio: los imprime tal cual, quedando bajo "ic".
4. %3d: igual al punto 2, pero tomando el siguiente argumento (`j`) y quedando encolumnados bajo "ión".
5. Cierro paréntesis y espacio: los imprime tal cual.
6. %9d: igual al punto 2 pero con el argumento `matriz[i][j]` y en 9 espacios, para alinearlos bajo "Valor".
7. \n: pasa a la línea siguiente, para poder imprimir correctamente los siguientes índices y valor.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió! Por favor me podrías dar una pequeña explicacion de como funciona ese tipo de posicionamiento? No entiendo como es que se van ubicando.

Comment: Ahí está. No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como solución.

Comment: Gracias!! Ya está

Answer (score 0):

Por cada iteracion debes hacer un salto de linea, la logica es sencilla escribe una columna por cada fila.

- `%d` significa digito y se van posicionando segun el orden en que coloques las variables, puedes leer que tipos de `%` existen [aqui](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). Los numeros que van antes de la `d` son el padding o espaciado(es una forma simplificada de insertar espacios vacios  ).
- `printf` tiene parametros, el primer campo va a ser lo que se va a imprimir y los subsecuentes son aquelas variables que vas a utilizar dentro del primer campo el cual esta en `"apostofes"`

```
    int matriz[3][3] = {(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)};
    //para imprimir solo valores
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf(" %d ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //para imprimir posiciones y valores
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("( %d, %d ) :  %d ", i, j, matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
```